# Video streaming over Rosbridge

Tags: ros-noetic, rosbridge, video

I'm researching what is the best way to stream video using a video camera, over Rosbridge, to a browser. What are the options out there?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! The following dicussion may help: https://discourse.ros.org/t/5-ways-to-stream-video-from-robots-and-why-you-should-use-webrtc/33865